# How to command autopilot to start a fixed rate descent?

Tags: safety, autopilot

Is it possible to command an autopilot to start a fixed rate descent? For example to avoid weather during the cruise phase? From what I have read the autopilot would maintain constant speed and altitude until interrupted but havent found a fixed rate descent function.

Comment: The answer greatly depends on the type of autopilot used. Small cessna's and the like generally have less advanced autoflight systems than aircraft made by Airbus or Boeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what typical autopilot controls look like

[image]
<sub><sub>Image source: [What is a "Flight Director"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/what-is-a-flight-director)</sub></sub>

The pilot can set the required altitude, as well as the required vertical speed to get to that altitude. A cruise decent will typically use a shallower descent than an approach descent.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/110/7874) explains that there is a flight level change mode and a vertical speed mode. The latter will hold vertical speed until a target altitude is reached.